# Within-subject two conditions and one variable with several categories

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, repeated-measures

I have a within-subject design where I compare two conditions: experimental and control. However the variable has 4 categories and I would also like to see which categories are causing that difference. I don't know which test I should run. I tried with t-test, but I am not sure.

For example variable F = total number of fruits consumed, where the fruits are of four different kinds: A (apples), B (bananas), C (cherries), D (dates)

First I want to know if there is difference in F in experimental and control condition.

I run t-tests and I found significant difference for F (p<0.05).

Now I run t-tests comparing A, B, C, D in both conditions, and I find that there is a significant difference in Apples (p<0.001) but not in the other categories. I just wonder if I chose the correct tests. The t-test for comparing the totals seems to make sense to me, but I wonder if some other test would make more sense in this case. Also for the multiple comparisons, should I use bonferroni correction?

Comment: For others to assist you, you will need to provide more detail about the nature of the variables in your model.  For example, it is completely unclear what you mean when you say 4 categories, yet write A+B+C+D. Or, if what is meant by Ae vs. Ac.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gregg. F is for example the total number of fruits consumed. There are four different kinds of fruits: apples (A), bananas (B), cherries (C), dates (D). Now, I would like to know if there is a difference in the total quantity of fruits consumed, but I would also like to know which fruits are mainly responsible for that difference. When I say Ae vs Ac I mean apples consumed in experimental condition vs apples consumed in control condition.